# Linux shell command to filter a text file by line length

Tags: sed, filter, awk, strings

I have a 30gb disk image of a borked partition (think `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=diskimage`) that I need to recover some text files from. Data carving tools like `foremost` only work on files with well defined headers, i.e. not plain text files, so I've fallen back on my good friend `strings`.

`strings diskimage > diskstrings.txt` produced a 3gb text file containing a bunch of strings, mostly useless stuff, mixed in with the text that I actually want.

Most of the cruft tends to be really long, unbroken strings of gibberish. The stuff I'm interested in is guaranteed to be less than 16kb, so I'm going to filter the file by line length.  Here's the Python script I'm using to do so:

```
infile  = open ("infile.txt" ,"r");
outfile = open ("outfile.txt","w");
for line in infile:
    if len(line) < 16384:
        outfile.write(line)
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

This works, but for future reference: Are there any magical one-line incantations (think `awk`, `sed`) that would filter a file by line length?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
awk '{ if (length($0) < 16384) print }' yourfile >your_output_file.txt
```

would print lines shorter than 16 kilobytes, as in your own example.

Or if you fancy Perl:

```
perl -nle 'if (length($_) < 16384) { print }' yourfile >your_output_file.txt
```

Comment: Added also Perl version :-)

Comment: And the awk script can be written as `awk 'length($0) < 16384' file > output`, as the default action is to print the line.

Comment: Note that some preinstalled awk versions don't support diacritics

Answer (score 12):

This is similar to Ansgar's answer, but slightly faster in my tests:

```
awk 'length($0) < 16384' infile >outfile
```

It's the same speed as the other awk answers. It relies on the implicit `print` of a true expression, but doesn't need to take the time to split the line as Ansgar's does.

Note that AWK gives you an `if` for free. The command above is equivalent to:

```
awk 'length($0) < 16384 {print}' infile >outfile
```

There's no explicit `if` (or its surrounding set of curly braces) as in some of the other answers.

Here is a way to do it in `sed`:

```
sed '/.\{16384\}/d' infile >outfile
```

or:

```
sed -r '/.{16384}/d' infile >outfile
```

which delete any line that contains 16384 (or more) characters.

For completeness, here's how you'd use `sed` to save lines longer than your threshold:

```
sed '/^.\{0,16383\}$/d' infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really different from the answers already given, but shorter still:

```
awk -F '' 'NF < 16384' infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `awk` such as:

```
$ awk '{ if (length($0) < 16384) { print } }' /path/to/text/file
```

This will print the lines longer shorter than 16K characters (16 * 1024).

You can use `grep` also:

```
$ grep ".\{,16384\}" /path/to/text/file
```

This will print the lines at most 16K characters.

Comment: Not sure `grep` is such a good idea - it's a simple regexp, to be sure, but more computationally expensive than `awk`.

"A man with problem says "I'll use regular expressions!" Now he has two problems." ;)

Comment: It is just another way of doing it. The first option I posted was using `awk`.

Comment: +1 for the regexp, because it golfs better, and it does not make me read awk manpages =)